# Error al trasladar el campo fecha desde base de datos hacia Excel

Tags: php, mysqli, excel

Buenas tardes comunidad.

Se me presenta el siguiente problema:

Cuando quiero quiero recorrer una tabla de base de datos todo llega perfecto excepto el campo recogido como fecha_hora que es un **timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

Todos los datos los recibo bien (salvando el UTF-8) excepto en este campo donde me llega el mensaje:

> Notice: Undefined index: fecha_hora in C:\xampp\htdocs....php on line 135

Recibo 26 campos perfectamente apareciendo este error en el último.

Cabecera:

```
<?php 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyExcel.xlsx");  //File name extension was wrong
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
?>
```

Recorriendo la tabla tanto por **foreach** como por **foreach** el error es el mismo

Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Saludos Jose, edita tu pregunta agregando el código que nos permite reproducir tu escenario, como verás, sólo con un error y una cabecera, es poco probable reproducir el caso, del mismo modo, al menos coloca un ejemplo de ese archivo de excel, detallado todo lo que sea necesario.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Ni siquiera alcanzo a entender qué es lo que intentas hacer. Parecería que es sacar datos de la base de datos y crear con ellos un archivo `Excel` ¿? Convendría que muestres el código donde dices que sale el *`Undefined index`*  y a qué se refieren esos datos, si a columnas de una tabla de la base de datos, etc.